# Setting up various DNS records for my mail server with external DNS

Tags: email, dns, cpanel

I have a domain name, `mysite.com` registered with a provider at `ns1.dnsprovider.com` and `ns2.dnsprovider.com`.

`mysite.com` is a Wordpress site on WHM/cPanel at IP: `111.222.333.444`

I can set my DNS records at DNSProvider to point at `111.222.333.444` for the websites - no problem.  I also need to set up email facilities.

This I'm struggling with.  I'm simply running the standard Exim package in cPanel.

I figure I need to set up an `A` record `mail.mysite.com` for IP `111.222.333.444` but I also need to set up `MX` records.  Would this be to `mail.mysite.com` with priority 0 and 10?

Also what about DKIM and SPF records?  What would I need to enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a quick note: If the mail server is on the same IP address you do not need the extra `A record`, since there is already an `A record` the `MX` record can use.
As for the `MX record`, it depends on what the mail addresses will be. For the one you mentioned the mail addresses will be `user@mail.example.com`, if you want them to be `user@example.com`, then the `MX record` must be for `example.com`, like this:

```
@ MX 10 mail.example.com.
```

Where `mail.example.com` is the extra  `A record` you wanted to create, you can also point the record to `example.com`, since it has an `A record` pointed to the IP of the mail server.

Now for the `SPF record` it depends on which servers will be send mails on behalf of your domain. If only your server (this includes your web site, since they are on the same IP) the `SPF record` can be like this:

```
@ TXT "v=spf1 a -all"
```

This allows the IP of your `A record` to send mails and "forbids" everybody else.

The `DKIM record` is in the following format:

```
default._domainkey TXT "v=DKIM1; p=yourPublicKey"
```

You should generate `yourPublicKey` and also `a private key`, with which you will sign your mails (note that you can simply skip the whole `DKIM` part)